# Static variable count and writing function

Tags: c++

Write a function incrementByTen that uses a static variable count.
Each call to thefunction should displaythe value of count and then 
increment count by 10.Initialize count to be 0 at the start of the program.

I know how to do this by keep calling my main. but How do i do it using a function??

```
int main()

      {
         static int count = 0;
           count++;

               cout<<count<<endl;
               main();
               system("PAUSE");
               return 0;
       }
```

Comment: Make a new method ( at the text says, ) don't keep calling main.

Comment: Do you know how to create another function? It looks a lot like `main()` (because `main()` is a function).

Comment: Any [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on C++ will explain how to implement functions plus a whole lot more. I recommend you pick one up and start reading.

Comment: I know how to make a function. however, I am just having a hard time implementing this one. I am not suppose to use loops.

Comment: # include<iostream>

using namespace std;
# include<iomanip>
# include<cstdlib>

using std::setw;
int incrementByTen(int);



int main()
{
 int num1;
 incrementByTen(num1);
 cout<<incrementByTen<<endl;
 cin.get();
 return 0;
}

could u check out my errors please. 

 int incrementByTen(int count)

 {
  static int count = 0;
  count=count+10;

  cout<<count<<endl;
  incrementByTen();
  return incrementByTen;
 }

Answer (score 4):

You rename it. (You may want to remove the call to `system` if that was meant to stay in `main`, but do note that it's not very portable and may or may not work on one OS. An alternative to `system("pause")` is `std::cin.get()`. Although this is only testcode, it's important to get used to good practices.)

Also, never call `main`.

§3.6.1.3 of the standard states:

> The function main shall not be used within a program.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

// Create count as a static variable and initialize it to 0
static int count = 0;

// Function that increases count by ten
static void IncrementByTen()
{
    std::cout<<count<< std::endl;
    count+= 10;
}

int main()
{   
    // As long as count is less or equal to 100
    while ( count <= 100 )
    {
        // Print and increment

        IncrementByTen();
    }

    // Wait for user to hit enter
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

`count` is now a static variable, and can be accessed from any function. You could also have `IncrementByTen()` call itself, and add check for if it's more than 100 in the function itself, kinda like this

```
#include <iostream>

// Function that increases count by ten
static void IncrementByTen()
{
    // Create count as a static variable and initialize it to 0 the first time this function is called
    static int count = 0;

   std::cout<<count<< std::endl;
    count+= 10;
    if ( count <= 100 )
        IncrementByTen();
    else
        return;
}

int main()
{   
    // Print and increment
    IncrementByTen();

    // Wait for user to hit enter
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's not much point to a global here. If `main` needs to know what it is, return the new value.

Comment: @chris Agree, a local variable would suffice. But the text specified static.

Comment: Yeah, a static local variable.

Comment: @chris I updated the answer, but technically the local static variable is initialized at started, or rather; it's initialized to 0 at startup, the re-initialized when the function is called.

Comment: The local one is initialized on first use to my knowledge.

Comment: @chris Yeah, but it is also zero-initialized on startup.

Comment: I invite you to look at [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=225ede0116ac38586e7b18fd136e3898-1dfa45f65786f4a26064bc85b3de325a).

Comment: @chris Take a look at the standard concerning zero-initialization ( 8.5 - 5 ) It states that zero-initialization does not mean calling the constructor. I would copy the section, but it's too large.

Comment: Interesting. I've read that section a few times before, but I don't think that ever registered.